# get error when trying to do null-coalescing operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, null

Trying to plan a string builder for a form submit:

```
try{
  top.document.getElementById("attributes").contentWindow.location = "attributeToolbar.aspx?el_id=" + (t_selected.attr("id").match(intRegex)[0] || "new") + "&opts="+ form_to_server();
}catch(err){
  alert(err);
  //prints:   TypeError: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined.
}
```

I was thinking to part a regex a match and if there isnt a match assign it to "new" to show it isnt in the jquery object.

The key area in the above statement is:

```
(t_selected.attr("id").match(intRegex)[0] || "new")
```

Comment: The error might be crashing it BEFORE it gets to the operator, maybe?

Comment: Note that there is no null-coalescing operator, this is simply a boolean OR although it has the same effect in this case. But if the value you're testing against is anything "falsy" (e.g. 0, false, "") then you will also get the value `"new"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test for a match, do:

```
... intRegex.test(t_selected.attr("id")) ...
```

instead. If the "match" call returns `null`, the array index operator will give you that error.

Comment: Well, under normal circumstances, I would be extracting the first element which is why i was getting the first matched element.  Maybe it would be better to split it onto multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
(t_selected.attr("id").match(intRegex) || ["new"])[0]
```

This will give you the complete match (if found) or the string "new".